# Manipulating the calendar in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

I'm currently creating an auction website using asp and vb.net. I want to manipulate the calendar so that only dates after the current date are selectable. How can I go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do it manually, I think.  If the user selects an earlier date (you can gauge this with the "Changed" event), you can restore it to the current date and give an error message.

For example (in regular VB.NET)

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
         If DateTimePicker1.Value < Now Then
            DateTimePicker1.Value = Now
            MsgBox("Error!")
         End If
    End Sub
```

Or, more directly, using the `MinDate` property of the control:

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Today
```

Comment: Thanks, that logic works. Just thought there might be a way for those dates to not be selectable at all. i.e. blacked out or something

Comment: @Matt Yes, I should have read the docs a bit more closely, there is a property of the control that does this.